# F# Type providers and Sky Biometry

Tags: f#, type-providers, f#-data

Has anyone used the F# type providers with [Sky Biometry](https://www.skybiometry.com/)?

A majority of the calls work great with the type providers.  However, when I call the faces/recognize method, I am getting fails using both the Json and the Xml type provider.

Using the Json one, I declare the type like this:

```
type skybiometryJsonFaceRecognition = JsonProvider<"http://api.skybiometry.com/fc/faces/recognize.json?uids=default@ImageComparer&urls=https://lg2014dev.blob.core.windows.net/d69bdda9-d934-448c-acae-99019f3a564f/01ee184f-ff0b-426f-872a-cbc81ef58d90.jpg&api_key=XXXXX&api_secret=yyyyy">
```

When I try and use the type in my code, it is failing on the last part of the graph:

```
let recognition = skybiometryJsonFaceRecognition.Load(stringBuilder.ToString())
```

It should be:

```
recognition.Photos.[0].Tags.[0].Uids.[0].confidence
```

But instead I get:

```
recognition.Photos.[0].Tags.[0].Uids.[0].JsonValue
```

I then swapped over to the Xml type provider for just this one call and I am getting intellisense working:

```
let recognition = skybiometryXmlFaceRecognition.Load(stringBuilder.ToString())
recognition.Photos.Photo.Tags.Tag.Uids.Uid.Confidence
```

But when I run it, I get

*System.Xml.XmlException: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.*

Looking at the XML in a call from my browser, it sure looks fine to me:

[image]

Does anyone have any suggestions?  Thanks

Comment: `let recognition = skybiometryXmlFaceRecognition.Load(stringBuilder.ToString())`

 Does stringbuilder here contain xml or url?

Comment: let stringBuilder = new StringBuilder()
        stringBuilder.Append(skybiometryUri) |> ignore
        stringBuilder.Append("/fc/faces/recognize.json?uids=") |> ignore
        stringBuilder.Append(uid) |> ignore
        stringBuilder.Append("&urls=") |> ignore
        stringBuilder.Append(imageUri) |> ignore
        stringBuilder.Append("&api_key=") |> ignore
        stringBuilder.Append(apiKey) |> ignore
        stringBuilder.Append("&api_secret=") |> ignore
        stringBuilder.Append(apiSecret) |> ignore

Comment: As a debugging option, you can download xml first and try load it from local storage. Probably, server response is not consistent.

Comment: Is there a preceeding `xml` tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to ntr's suggestion, I changed the type def to use local storage.  The Json TP then found all of the props and the actual call worked as expected.  Thanks everyone.

Comment: What version of F# Data were you using? If it still repros on 2.0.9, please report the problem at https://github.com/fsharp/FSharp.Data/issues